# Can I use DPWS on desktop windows

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, web-services, .net-micro-framework

I am working on a project that involes both PC and embedded device. The PC will running windows or linux + mono runtime. The embedded device will be using .NET MF.

It is kinda industral control system, I'm considering using DPWS for the communication.

The ability to discover devices and hosted service is important for me. And eventing is also required. And I need to host services on both PC and embedded device, and consume services on both platform as well. The whole project need to be implemented using .NET of .NETMF.

Is that possible? I really can not find anything about using DPWS on PC.

If not possible do I have something else? upnp?

Comment: By DPWS do you mean this - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devices_Profile_for_Web_Services?

Comment: @ChrisF, Yes the Devices Profile for Web Services, I dont know if there is any .NET lib doing this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked extensively for the same thing recently and concluded that there is no publicly available desktop .Net Dpws stack.

[Dpws web service with event - Wcf client example or suggestions sought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358039/dpws-web-service-with-event-wcf-client-example-or-suggestions-sought)